# SAM card authentication failed

Tags: c#, smartcard

I should modify an existent software to write some data in Smart Cards. Today we are generating keys with an HSM. Now our client is requesting us to do that with a SAM card.

Now, I modified the software, and it works fine when debugging attached to VS. When I try to run the app outside VS, SAM authentication fails.

The situation is: we should use a C++ library in order to generate the APDU commands for the SAM cards, and this library is delivered to us by our client, so we have a black box. The SAM cards are also delivered by our client. I received also a CLI app that do the same operations than the DLL.

I developed a wrapper for the DLL and another one for the CLI app. When I run my application using the CLI wrapper it works fine when debugging and when I run it outside VS (installed app). When I try to run it using the DLL, it works fine when debugging on VS, but SAM authentication fails when I run it outside VS.

In both cases the C# code is the same (DLL wrapper or CLI wrapper) and only changes the running environment (debugging under VS or direct run from Windows). The library is loading correctly, apparently all its dependencies also, so I don't understand where is the problem.

```
public bool AuthenticateOnSamCard(PCSCReader reader, string transportKey)
{
      // Step 1
      var apduStep1 = SAMHandlerCommandExecutor.AuthStep1();
      reader.SCard.Connect(reader.SCard.ReaderName, SCARD_SHARE_MODE.Shared, SCARD_PROTOCOL.Tx);

      var response = reader.Exchange(apduStep1); //-> Auth step 
      var dataStep1 = SAMHandlerCommandExecutor.GetData(response);

      if (dataStep1[0][0] != 1)
      {
          reader.SCard.Disconnect();
          return false;
      }

      // Step 2
      var apduStep2 = SAMHandlerCommandExecutor.AuthStep2(transportKey, dataStep1[1]);
      response = reader.Exchange(apduStep2[0]); //-> Auth step 2
      var dataStep2 = SAMHandlerCommandExecutor.GetData(response);

      if (dataStep2[0][0] != 1)
      {
           reader.SCard.Disconnect();
           return false;
      }

      // Step 3
      var apduStep3 = SAMHandlerCommandExecutor.AuthStep3(transportKey, dataStep2[1], apduStep2);
      response = reader.Exchange(apduStep3);

      if (SAMHandlerCommandExecutor.Verify(response))
      {
            Console.WriteLine($"Sam Authentication OK");
            Program.Logger.Info($"Sam Authentication OK");
            return true;
      }

      return false;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you confirm that it fails only at Step 3?
Does it also fail when you launch it with a debugger with no breakpoints?

Comment: It fails on step 2, when I send the APDU command to the SAM, always running directly from Windows. When I run it debugging the authentication runs correctly, with or without breakpoints, and method finishes normally.

Comment: Hmm. Without any other knowledge like this, i would only advise to check that there are no uninitialized/poorly initialized data in the wrapper that would be sent to the C++ side. In a debugger this data would be set to 0 and not provoke a bad behavior, but directly run it could be garbage data.